# Hierarchy theorem for NTIME intersect coNTIME?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, nondeterminism, time-hierarchy, hierarchy-theorems

$\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}$Does a theorem along the following lines hold: If $g(n)$ is a little bigger than $f(n)$, then $\cc{NTIME}(g) \cap \cc{coNTIME}(g) \neq \cc{NTIME}(f) \cap \cc{coNTIME}(f)$?

It's easy to show that $\cc{NP} \cap \cc{coNP} \neq \cc{NEXP} \cap \cc{coNEXP}$, at least. Proof: Assume not. Then $$\cc{NEXP} \cap \cc{coNEXP} \subseteq \cc{NP} \cap \cc{coNP} \subseteq \cc{NP} \cup \cc{coNP} \subseteq \cc{NEXP} \cap \cc{coNEXP},$$ so $\cc{NP} = \cc{coNP}$, and hence (by padding) $\cc{NEXP} = \cc{coNEXP}$. But then our assumption implies that $\cc{NP} = \cc{NEXP}$, contradicting the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem. QED.

But I don't even see how to separate $\cc{NP} \cap \cc{coNP}$ from $\cc{NSUBEXP} \cap \cc{coNSUBEXP}$, as diagonalization seems tricky in this setting.

Comment: The intersection is a semantic class, and [we don't know how to prove hierarchy theorems for semantic classes](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4461/).

Answer (score 1):

(This would've been a comment, but it doesn't render properly when I try that.)

"I don't even see how to separate" $\;\;\;$[$\mathbf{U}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up)$\mathbf{q}$[$\mathbf{uasiLIN}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#ql) $\cap \; \mathbf{coUquasiLIN} \;\;\;$ from

$[$the [linear-exponent](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#e) version of [QIP[2]](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qip2)$] \;\; \cap \;\; [$the linear-exponent version of coQIP[2]$] \;\;\;\;\;$.