# Does there exist the idea of "RP-complete", like NP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

**NP**-hardness and **NP**-completeness play an important role in complexity theory. 
My question is, does there exist a language $L$ in **RP** 
to which any language $M$ in **RP** can be reduced in polynomial time?
We can say that such a language $L$ is "**RP**-complete", if exists, but I cannot find any information about this idea. Can anyone tell me about it, please?

Comment: This question is not research level. Should have been migrated to computer science stack exchange.

Comment: @TayfunPay given that this is an open problem, I think it should be considered research level.

Comment: @TayfunPay Borderline. The literal question being asked (essentially, is there such a thing of **RP**-completeness) is not research-level but the closely related question of whether any such problems exist appears to be open so is research-level.

Comment: @TayfunPay Sorry about that. Maybe I should have posted this on CS stack exchange. However, thanks to David Richerby's helpful answer and others' comments, I think now this topic has research-level value as a whole, so I want to keep it on this site. Any way, I'll be careful on which site to post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: If you open any good computational complexity book and read it, you will get the answer for this question. So in my opinion, it is still not research level. I have seen numerous questions down voted for the same reason.

Answer (score 9):

Yes: the concept of "**X**-complete under **Y**-reductions" exists for any complexity class **X** and any class **Y** of reductions.  However, there may or may not be any complete problems under this definition, depending on what **X** and **Y** are. For example, it is well-known that **NP** has complete problems under polynomial-time, logspace and even first-order reductions, but it does not have complete problems under linear-time reductions as this would violate the time hierarchy theorem.

As far as I can see, it is open whether there is a class of reductions under which **RP** has complete problems. The issue is that it is a so-called *semantic class*: it is defined by a non-computable set of Turing machines, namely polynomial-time randomized Turing machines with the undecidable requirement that, for every input, either every path rejects or at least half accept. See [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/semantic-vs-syntactic-complexity-classes) for more details on the issues surrounding complete problems for semantic classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear and useful answer! 
Didn't know that **RP** is such a complicated class.

Comment: Are there no approximation problems complete for RP?

Comment: @PeterShor **RP** is a class of decision problems so an approximation problem could only be **RP**-hard. There are certainly **RP**-hard problems, since **RP** is included in **NP**.

Comment: @David: you can ***weaken*** the definition of "BPP-complete" such that it makes sense for approximation problems to be "BPP-complete". You can then find lots of interesting "BPP-complete" approximation problems. People who insist that only decision problems can be be BPP-complete are leaving vast areas of interesting complexity theory completely unexplored. Such a BPP-complete approximation problem should be both BPP-hard and solvable in $\mathrm{P}^\mathrm{BPP}$. Rephrasing my question, does a similar phenomenon exist with RP?

Comment: To add to what @PeterShor said, it is natural to consider promiseRP, for which the usual construction of complete problems should work. I think this is equivalent to what he is suggesting.

Comment: @Sasho: certainly for BPP, the correct formulation in promise problems and approximation problems are equivalent. I don't know whether that is true for RP.

Comment: @PeterShor The **X**-hard problems in **P^X** are a very natural thing to study (indeed, I've done so myself for **X=#P**) and it's perfectly possible to study them without abusing terminology by calling them "**X**-complete". I don't know if anybody has studied such problems for **RP**; it's a good question.

Comment: @David: I don't understand why this is such an evil abuse of terminology. If somebody who doesn't know the relevant material already asks about **X**-complete problems, where **X** is a randomized class like **BPP**, I think a discussion of **X**-hard problems in $\mathbf{P}^\mathbf{X}$ is much more useful than the answer "as far as we know, there are no **X**-complete problems".

Comment: @PeterShor It's an abuse of terminology because the definition of a problem being complete for a complexity class includes the requirement that the problem be in that class. But I agree that such problems are relevant to the question, if they exist.