# What are semantic classes that have a syntactic equivalent?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-list

This question is related to [Benefits for syntactic and semantic classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4792/benefits-for-syntactic-and-semantic-classes).
As mentioned there, $\mathsf{PSPACE} = \mathsf{IP}$, which can be interpreted as the semantic class $\mathsf{IP}$ obtaining a syntactic definition.
What are other non-trivial examples for "syntacticizing" a class?

Comment: Does MIP=NEXP count? Or is it too closely related to IP=PSPACE to count as *another* example? Also QIP=PSPACE?

Comment: Another example is ReachUL. See [this paper](https://link-springer-com.ezproxy.lib.utexas.edu/chapter/10.1007/BFb0023471).

Comment: @William I suggest you turn this into an answer with a link that doesn't require a U Texas account...

Comment: @domotorp Oops. Done.

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, the ostensibly semantic class APP defined in [1] was shown to be syntactic in [2].

[1] Valentine Kabanets, Charles Rackoff, Stephen A. Cook, *Efficiently
  approximable real-valued functions*, ECCC Report [TR00-034](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/eccc-reports/2000/TR00-034/), 2000.

[2] Emil Jeřábek, *Approximate counting in bounded arithmetic*, Journal of Symbolic Logic 72 (2007), no. 3, pp. 959–993. [doi](https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1191333850), [preprint](http://math.cas.cz/~jerabek/papers/apx.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

A few others; related to $\mathsf{IP} = \mathsf{PSPACE}$, but there are enough of them that weren't mentioned in the OQ that I figured it's worth putting them here:

- $\mathsf{QIP} = \mathsf{PSPACE}$ ([Jain-Ji-Upadhyay-Watrous](https://doi.org/10.1145/2049697.2049704), [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4737))
- $\mathsf{MIP} = \mathsf{NEXP}$ ([Babai-Fortnow-Lund](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01200430))
- The PCP Theorem $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{PCP}[\log n, O(1)]$ ([Arora-Safra](https://doi.org/10.1145/273865.273901), [Arora-Lund-Motwani-Sudan-Szegedy](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F278298.278306))

Answer (score 3):

Another example is $\mathbf{ReachUL}$, the class of languages decidable by nondeterministic log-space Turing machines such that for any input and any configuration, there is at most one sequence of nondeterministic choices leading to that configuration. See ["An unambiguous class possessing a complete set"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0023471) by Lange.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorites is $IND[t(n)] = FO[t(n)]$, where $IND[t(n)]$ is the class of problems decidable with an inductive definition which closes in less than or equal to $t(n)$ iterations and $FO[t(n)]$ are the problems decidable using a first order logic sentence with less than or equal to $t(n)$ iterated quantifier blocks.